# Multiprocessing loop and stop condition

Tags: loops, queue, pipe, python-multiprocessing

I just ported a script using the `multithreading` library to the `multiprocessing` library, therefore, I am encountering issues related to the way the memory is shared between processes.

Quick overview, my workers are consuming a queue of words; when a worker find a hit it should boradcast a signal (global variable or whatever implementation) to order the other running processes to terminate.

Here is the main method of my workers:

```
def run(self):
    while not self.queue.empty():
        entry = self.queue.get()

        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(self.token, entry, algorithm = 'HS256')
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            if self.verbose:
                print(DEBUG + "[{}] ".format(self.name) + "InvalidTokenError: " + Style.BRIGHT + entry + RESET)
            continue
        except jwt.DecodeError:
            print(WARNING + "[{}] ".format(self.name) + "DecodingError: " + Style.BRIGHT + entry + RESET)
            continue
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ERROR + "[{}] ".format(self.name) + "Exception: " + Style.BRIGHT + "{}".format(ex) + RESET)
            continue

        # Save the holy secret into a file in case sys.stdout is not responding
        with open("jwtpot.pot", "a+") as file:
            file.write("{0}:{1}:{2}".format(self.token, payload, entry))
            print(RESULT + "[{}] ".format(self.name) + "Secret key saved to location: " + Style.BRIGHT + "{}".format(file.name) + RESET)

        print(RESULT + "[{}] ".format(self.name) + "Secret key: " + Style.BRIGHT + entry + RESET) 
        print(RESULT + "[{}] ".format(self.name) + "Payload: " + Style.BRIGHT + "{}".format(payload) + RESET)

        break

        self.queue.task_done()
```

Here is how I instanciate and start my processes in my main:

```
# Load and segmentate the wordlist into the queue
            print(INFO + "Processing the wordlist..." + RESET)
            queue = populate_queue(queue, wordlist, verbose)

            print(INFO + "Total retrieved words: " + Style.BRIGHT + "{}".format(queue.qsize()) + RESET)

            for i in range(process_count):
                process = Process(queue, token, verbose)
                process.daemon = True
                print(INFO + "Starting {}".format(process.name) + RESET)
                process.start()
                processes.append(process)

            print(WARNING + "Pour yourself some coffee, this might take a while..." + RESET)

            # Block the parent-process until all the child-processes finish to process the queue
            for process in processes:
                process.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a (shared) pipe from all the sub-processes back to the parent. Then, the process that finds the secret key can write something to the pipe to indicate what was found. If a process doesn't find the secret key and the queue is empty, it just exits.

The parent simply waits until it gets something back from the pipe, which will happen either when a child writes to the pipe, or when all children have exited. It then kills all the remaining children that are still running.

Here's a quick hack demonstrating:

```
from multiprocessing import *
from time import sleep

def process(pid, rpipe, wpipe):
    rpipe.close()
    sleep(1 + pid * 0.1)
    if pid == 5:
        print("I found it!")
        wpipe.send((pid, "GOT IT"))
    print("Process %d exiting" % pid)
    wpipe.close()

def one_try(findit):
    processes = []
    rpipe, wpipe = Pipe()

    for i in range(15):
        # Start
        if i != 5 or findit:
            p = Process(target=process, args=(i, rpipe, wpipe))
            p.start()
            processes.append((i, p))

    # Close write pipe in the parent so we get EOF when all children are gone
    wpipe.close()
    try:
        pid, result = rpipe.recv()
        print("%s was found by %s" % (result, pid))
        print("Will kill other processes")
    except EOFError:
        print("Nobody found it!")
    rpipe.close()

    for i, p in processes:
        p.terminate()
        p.join()

one_try(True)        # Should have one process that finds it
one_try(False)       # Nobody found it
```